# MIPS Programs with more than 4 arguments

Tags: function, assembly, stack, mips, subroutine

The following is my code and the final test case. main and printStats are both given, I had to qrite average (which is at the bottom), so look there for problems. This case changes the value of all registers in $f, $t, $a, and $s and adds 2 items to the top of its stack in order to ensure that the average method is preserving properly the values it will need to run its calculations following the $jr from printStats.

The problem I am having is recurring in a few test cases where there are 3 batters. Batter 3 uses arbitrarily large integers.

```
# printStats puts two values at the top two spots in its stack.  This is where
#    the number of homeruns and outs were placed when printStats
#    is called.  A function is allowed to change its own stack.

# Changes the $s registers used by main. The average function should be
#    getting arguments from the $a registers and the stack, and not relying
#    on what is in the $s registers.

# From test12:
# Tests if $t registers are preserved (if needed) by average.
# printStats puts values into every $t register.

# From test13:
# Tests if $a registers used correctly when average calls printStats.
# printStats changes the contents of $a1, $a2, and $a3 before returning

# test with three batters, both average and slugging percentage
# First batter has no hits, but does have outs
# Second batter has hits and outs, with realistic values
# Third hitter has large values for some of the hits and for the
#    outs. This means the hits and outs *have* to be converted from int's
#    to float's in order to get the right answer. 

.data

mainNumBatters:
   .word 3

mainBatter1:
   .word  27      # walks
   .word   0      # singles
   .word   0      # doubles
   .word   0      # triples
   .word   0      # home runs
   .word 423      # outs
mainBatter2:
   .word  27      # walks
   .word 101      # singles
   .word  22      # doubles
   .word   4      # triples
   .word  10      # home runs
   .word 423      # outs

mainBatter3:
   .word   102322 # walks
   .word  8000000 # singles
   .word       22 # doubles
   .word   500000 # triples
   .word       10 # home runs
   .word 23000000 # outs


.data
mainNewline:
         .asciiz  "\n"
mainBatterNumber:
         .asciiz  "Batter number: "
mainBattingAverage:
         .asciiz  "Batting average: "
mainSluggingPercentage:
         .asciiz  "Slugging percentage: "
mainOnbasePercentage:
         .asciiz  "On-base percentage: "

         .text

main:
         # Function prologue -- even main has one
         addiu $sp, $sp, -24     # allocate stack space -- default of 24 here
         sw    $fp, 0($sp)       # save frame pointer of caller
         sw    $ra, 4($sp)       # save return address
         addiu $fp, $sp, 20      # setup frame pointer of main

         # for (i = 0; i < mainNumBatters; i++)
         #    compute batting average
         #    compute slugging average

         la    $s1, mainNumBatters
         lw    $s6, 0($s1)       # $s6 = number of batters
         addi  $s0, $zero, 0     # $s0 = i = 0
         la    $s1, mainBatter1  # $s1 = addr of current batter's stats

mainLoopBegin:
         slt   $t0, $s0, $s6     # $t0 = i < number of batters
         beq   $t0, $zero, mainDone

         la    $a0, mainBatterNumber
         addi  $v0, $zero, 4
         syscall
         addi  $a0, $s0, 1
         addi  $v0, $zero, 1
         syscall
         la    $a0, mainNewline
         addi  $v0, $zero, 4
         syscall

         # Compute the batting average
         addi  $a0, $zero, 1      # $a0 = 1 = compute batting average
         lw    $a1,   0($s1)      # $a1 = walks
         lw    $a2,   4($s1)      # $a2 = singles
         lw    $a3,   8($s1)      # $a3 = doubles
         lw    $s2,  12($s1)      # $s2 = triples
         lw    $s3,  16($s1)      # $s3 = home runs
         lw    $s4,  20($s1)      # $s4 = outs

         sw    $s4,  -4($sp)      # put outs at top of average's stack
         sw    $s3,  -8($sp)      # put homeruns 2nd fm top of average's stack
         sw    $s2, -12($sp)      # put triples 3rd fm top of average's stack
         jal   average

         # Print the batting average
         mtc1  $v0, $f12          # get result fm $v0 before we print string
         la    $a0, mainBattingAverage
         addi  $v0, $zero, 4
         syscall
         addi  $v0, $zero, 2      # print the average
         syscall
         la    $a0, mainNewline
         addi  $v0, $zero, 4
         syscall
         syscall

         # do it for the slugging percentage
         addi  $a0, $zero, 2      # $a0 = 2 = compute slugging average
         lw    $a1,   0($s1)      # $a1 = walks
         lw    $a2,   4($s1)      # $a2 = singles
         lw    $a3,   8($s1)      # $a3 = doubles
         lw    $s2,  12($s1)      # $s2 = triples
         lw    $s3,  16($s1)      # $s3 = home runs
         lw    $s4,  20($s1)      # $s4 = outs

         sw    $s4,  -4($sp)      # put outs at top of average's stack
         sw    $s3,  -8($sp)      # put homeruns 2nd fm top of average's stack
         sw    $s2, -12($sp)      # put triples 3rd fm top of average's stack
         jal   average

         # Print the slugging percentage
         mtc1  $v0, $f12          # get result fm $v0 before we print string
         la    $a0, mainSluggingPercentage
         addi  $v0, $zero, 4
         syscall
         addi  $v0, $zero, 2      # print the percentage
         syscall
         la    $a0, mainNewline
                 addi  $v0, $zero, 4
         syscall
         syscall

         # do it again for the on-base percentage
         addi  $a0, $zero, 3      # $a0 = 3 = compute slugging average
         lw    $a1,   0($s1)      # $a1 = walks
         lw    $a2,   4($s1)      # $a2 = singles
         lw    $a3,   8($s1)      # $a3 = doubles
         lw    $s2,  12($s1)      # $s2 = triples
         lw    $s3,  16($s1)      # $s3 = home runs
         lw    $s4,  20($s1)      # $s4 = outs

         sw    $s4,  -4($sp)      # put outs at top of average's stack
         sw    $s3,  -8($sp)      # put homeruns 2nd fm top of average's stack
         sw    $s2, -12($sp)      # put triples 3rd fm top of average's stack

         jal   average

         # Print the slugging percentage
         mtc1  $v0, $f12          # get result fm $v0 before we print string
         la    $a0, mainOnbasePercentage
         addi  $v0, $zero, 4
         syscall
         addi  $v0, $zero, 2      # print the percentage
         syscall
         la    $a0, mainNewline
         addi  $v0, $zero, 4
         syscall
         syscall

         addi  $s0, $s0, 1       # i++
         addi  $s1, $s1, 24      # $s1 = addr of next batter's stats
         j     mainLoopBegin

mainDone:
         # Epilogue for main -- restore stack & frame pointers and return
         lw    $ra, 4($sp)       # get return address from stack
         lw    $fp, 0($sp)       # restore frame pointer for caller
         addiu $sp, $sp, 24      # restore frame pointer for caller
                  jr    $ra               # return to caller

.data
printStatsOuts:
         .asciiz "Outs:      "
printStatsWalks:
         .asciiz "Walks:     "
printStatsSingles:
         .asciiz "Singles:   "
printStatsDoubles:
         .asciiz "Doubles:   "
printStatsTriples:
         .asciiz "Triples:   "
printStatsHomeruns:
         .asciiz "Home runs: "
printStatsNewline:
         .asciiz "\n"

.text
printStats:
         # Function prologue
         addiu $sp, $sp, -32     # allocate stack space
         sw    $a3, 20($sp)      # save $a0 thru $a3
         sw    $a2, 16($sp)
         sw    $a1, 12($sp)
         sw    $a0, 8($sp)
         sw    $ra, 4($sp)       # save return address
         sw    $fp, 0($sp)       # save frame pointer of caller
         addiu $fp, $sp, 28      # setup frame pointer of average

         # printStats expects to find the following:
         # $a0 = walks
         # $a1 = singles
         # $a2 = doubles
         # $a3 = triples
         # 5th argument = homeruns
         # 6th argument = outs

         # print the outs
         la    $a0, printStatsOuts
                  syscall
         lw    $a0, 0($fp)       # the outs are at the top of our stack
         addi  $v0, $zero, 1
         syscall
         la    $a0, printStatsNewline
         addi  $v0, $zero, 4
         syscall

         # print the walks
         la    $a0, printStatsWalks
         addi  $v0, $zero, 4
         syscall
         lw    $a0, 8($sp)       # the walks were passed in $a0
         addi  $v0, $zero, 1
         syscall
         la    $a0, printStatsNewline
         addi  $v0, $zero, 4
         syscall

         # print the singles
         la    $a0, printStatsSingles
         addi  $v0, $zero, 4
         syscall
         addi  $a0, $a1, 0        # the singles were passed in $a1
         addi  $v0, $zero, 1
         syscall
         la    $a0, printStatsNewline
         addi  $v0, $zero, 4
         syscall

         # print the doubles
         la    $a0, printStatsDoubles
         addi  $v0, $zero, 4
         syscall
         addi  $a0, $a2, 0        # the doubles were passed in $a2
         addi  $v0, $zero, 1
         syscall
         la    $a0, printStatsNewline
         addi  $v0, $zero, 4
         syscall

         # print the triples
         la    $a0, printStatsTriples
         addi  $v0, $zero, 4
         syscall
         addi  $a0, $a3, 0        # the doubles were passed in $a3
         addi  $v0, $zero, 1
         syscall
         la    $a0, printStatsNewline
         addi  $v0, $zero, 4
         syscall

         # print the homeruns
         la    $a0, printStatsHomeruns
         addi  $v0, $zero, 4
         syscall
         lw    $a0, -4($fp)       # the homeruns are 4 bytes below the top of our stack
         addi  $v0, $zero, 1
         syscall
         la    $a0, printStatsNewline
         addi  $v0, $zero, 4
         syscall

         # Put -1 in $t0, then copy that value to each of the $f registers
         addi  $t0, $zero, -1
         mtc1  $t0, $f0
         mtc1  $t0, $f1
         mtc1  $t0, $f2
         mtc1  $t0, $f3
         mtc1  $t0, $f4
         mtc1  $t0, $f5
         mtc1  $t0, $f6
         mtc1  $t0, $f7
         mtc1  $t0, $f8
         mtc1  $t0, $f9
         mtc1  $t0, $f10
         mtc1  $t0, $f11
         mtc1  $t0, $f12
         mtc1  $t0, $f13
                 mtc1  $t0, $f14
         mtc1  $t0, $f15
         mtc1  $t0, $f16
         mtc1  $t0, $f17
         mtc1  $t0, $f18
         mtc1  $t0, $f19
         mtc1  $t0, $f20
         mtc1  $t0, $f21
         mtc1  $t0, $f22
         mtc1  $t0, $f23
         mtc1  $t0, $f24
         mtc1  $t0, $f25
         mtc1  $t0, $f26
         mtc1  $t0, $f27
         mtc1  $t0, $f28
         mtc1  $t0, $f29
         mtc1  $t0, $f30
         mtc1  $t0, $f31

         # Put various values in the $t registers
         addi  $t0, $zero, -1111
         addi  $t1, $zero, -2222
         addi  $t2, $zero, -3333
         addi  $t3, $zero, -4444
         addi  $t4, $zero, -5555
         addi  $t5, $zero, -6666
         addi  $t6, $zero, -7777
         addi  $t7, $zero, -8888
         addi  $t8, $zero, -9999
         addi  $t9, $zero, -1111

         # Put various values in the $a registers.
         addi  $a0, $zero, -1111
         addi  $a1, $zero, -1111
         addi  $a2, $zero, -2222
         addi  $a3, $zero, -3333
                  # Put two values at the top two spots in our stack.  This is where
         #    the number of homeruns and outs were placed when printStats
         #    is called.  A function is allowed to change its own stack.
         addi  $t7, $zero, -1234
         sw    $t7,  0($fp)
         sw    $t7, -4($fp)

printStatsDone:
         # Epilogue for printStats -- restore stack & frame pointers and return
         lw    $ra, 4($sp)       # get return address from stack
         lw    $fp, 0($sp)       # restore frame pointer for caller
         addiu $sp, $sp, 32      # restore frame pointer for caller
         jr    $ra               # return to caller

# Your code goes below this line

average: 
    #takes 7 arguments
    #Arguments $a0-$a3 are put on the Caller's stack
    #arguments 5-7 are put on the Callee's stack and called

# Prologue: set up stack and frame pointers for average
        addiu   $sp, $sp, -36    # allocate stack space -- 36 needed here
        sw      $fp, 0($sp)      # save caller's frame pointer
        sw      $ra, 4($sp)      # save return address
        # save parameter values $a0-$a3 on the stack
        sw      $a0, 8($sp) # designates which calculation to do
        sw      $a1, 12($sp)    # walks
        sw      $a2, 16($sp)    # singles
        sw      $a3, 20($sp)    # doubles
        addiu   $fp, $sp, 32    # setup average frame pointer

    #Allocate proper locations of arguments for printStats
    #arguments 5 and 6 (home runs and outs will be placed on stack)
    addi    $t5, $a0, 0 #$t5 designates which calculation to run
    addi    $a0, $a1, 0 #walks of printStats
    addi    $a1, $a2, 0 #singles of printStats
    addi    $a2, $a3, 0 #doubles of printStats
    lw  $a3, 24($sp)    #triples of printStats
    lw  $t1, 28($sp)    #home runs of printStat
    sw  $t1, -8($sp)    #home runs now 2nd from top of stack
    lw  $t2, 32($sp)    #outs of printStats
    sw  $t2, -4($sp)    #out now top of stack
    jal printStats

    #restore registers used in average
    lw  $t2, 32($sp)    #outs
    lw  $t1, 28($sp)    #homeruns
    lw  $a3, 24($sp)    #triples
    lw  $a2, 20($sp)    #doubles
    lw  $a1, 16($sp)    #singles
    lw  $a0, 12($sp)    #walks
    lw  $t5, 8($sp) #compare which calculation to run   

    #convert outs to float
    mtc1    $t2, $f4    #outs = $f4

    #hits
        #hits = singles + doubles + triples + home runs
        add     $t3, $a1, $a2   # hits = singles + doubles
        add     $t3, $t3, $a3   # hits = $t3 + triples
        add     $t3, $t3, $t1   # hits = $t3 + home runs
    mtc1    $t3, $f1        #convert hits to float $f1

        #atBats
        #atBats = hits + outs
        add.s   $f2, $f1, $f4   # atBats = hits + outs
    mfc1    $t4, $f2        #convert atBats to int for compare

    #Compare $t5
    #if $t5 == 1, computer batting average
    #if $t5 == 2, compute slugging percentage
    #if $t5 == 3, compute on-base percentage

    addi    $t0, $zero, 1   #$t0 = 1
    beq $t5, $t0, averageBattingAverage

    addi    $t0, $zero, 2   #$t0 = 2
    beq $t5, $t0, averageSluggingPercentage

    addi    $t0, $zero, 3   #$t0 = 3
    beq $t5, $t0, averageOnBasePercentage

averageBattingAverage:
    #batting average
    #batting average = hits/atBats
    #if atBats == 0, average = 0

    #compare atBats
    beq     $t4, $zero, averageBattingSluggingZero

    #batting
    div.s   $f3, $f1, $f2   #batting average = hits/atBats

    #Set to print
    mfc1    $v0, $f3    #return $v0 the batting average
    j   averageDone #done

averageSluggingPercentage:
    #Slugging percentage
    #slugging percentage = (singles + doubles*2 + triples*3
    #           + home runs*4)/atBats 
    #if atBats == 0, percentage = 0

    #compare atBats
    beq     $t4, $zero, averageBattingSluggingZero

    #slugging
    add $t5, $a2, $a2   #doubles*2
    add $t6, $a3, $a3   #$t6 = triples * 2
    add $t6, $t6, $a3   #$t6 = triples * 3
    add $t7, $t1, $t1   #$t7 = home runs * 2
    add $t7, $t7, $t7   #$t7 = home runs * 4
    add $t8, $a1, $t5   #$t8 = singles + doubles*2
    add $t8, $t8, $t6   #$t8 = $t8 + triples*3
    add $t8, $t8, $t7   #$t8 = $t8 + home runs*4
    mtc1    $t8, $f1    #convert $t8 to float $f1
    div.s   $f3, $f1, $f2   #slugging percentage = $f1/atBats

    #set to print
    mfc1    $v0, $f3        #return $v0 the slugging percentage
    j   averageDone #done   

averageOnBasePercentage:
    #On-base percentages
    #on-base percentages = (hits + walks)/(atBats + walks)
    #if atBats + walks is zero, percentage is zero

    add $t6, $t3, $a0   #$t6 = hits + walks
    add $t7, $t4, $a0   #$t7 = atBats + walks

    #compare atBats + walks
    beq $t7, $zero, averageOnBaseZero

    #on-base
    mtc1    $t6, $f1    #convert $t6 to float $f6
    mtc1    $t7, $f2    #convert $t7 to float $f7
    div.s   $f3, $f1, $f2   #on-base percentage = $f6/$f7

    #set to print
    mfc1    $v0, $f3        #return $v0 the on-base percentage
    j   averageDone #done   

averageBattingSluggingZero:
    #if atBats is zero, batting average and slugging
    #percentage are both zero

    addi    $t0, $zero, 0   #$t0 = 0
    mtc1    $t0, $f0    #convert 0 to float $f0

    #set to print
    mfc1    $v0, $f0        #return $v0 = 0 
    j       averageDone     #done

averageOnBaseZero:
    #if atBats + walks is zero, on-base percentage
    # is also zero

    addi    $t0, $zero, 0   #$t0 = 0
    mtc1    $t0, $f0    #convert 0 to float $f0

    #set to print
    mfc1    $v0, $f0        #return $v0 = 0
    j       averageDone     #done

averageDone:  # Epilogue: restore stack and frame pointers and return
        lw      $ra, 4($sp)      # get return address from stack
        lw      $fp, 0($sp)      # restore the caller's frame pointer
        addiu   $sp, $sp, 36     # restore the caller's stack pointer
        jr      $ra              # return to caller's code
```

My outputs are not lining up and I don't get why.
The following is the correct output for batter 3.

```
Batter number: 3
Outs:      23000000
Walks:     102322
Singles:   8000000
Doubles:   22
Triples:   500000
Home runs: 10
Batting average: 0.26984200

Outs:      23000000
Walks:     102322
Singles:   8000000
Doubles:   22
Triples:   500000
Home runs: 10
Slugging percentage: 0.30158967

Outs:      23000000
Walks:     102322
Singles:   8000000
Doubles:   22
Triples:   500000
Home runs: 10
On-base percentage: 0.27220613
```

And here's my output, with a ! to mark the inconsistencies

```
Batter number: 3
Outs:      23000000
Walks:     102322
Singles:   8000000
Doubles:   22
Triples:   500000
Home runs: 10
!Batting average: 0.22532867

Outs:      23000000
Walks:     102322
Singles:   8000000
Doubles:   22
Triples:   500000
Home runs: 10
!Slugging percentage: 0.25183919

Outs:      23000000
Walks:     102322
Singles:   8000000
Doubles:   22
Triples:   500000
Home runs: 10
!On-base percentage: 0.22559348
```

How are my calculations off for this one batter, and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: Fixed. For anyone that stumbles on this with the same problems:
I had to use 
int to float
mtc1 $t, $f
cvt.s.w $f, $f #same $f reg

and float to int
cvt.w.s $f, $f #same $f reg
mfc1 $t, $f
to preserve my values and get the right values

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple calling conventions, you should figure out which one you are supposed to follow. If you have no documentation, you could look at compiler-generated assembly code, or use a debugger.

That said, judging from the fact that only 4 arguments are passed on the stack, you seem to be using the `O32` calling convention. This means, the stack upon entry to your function contains 4 argument slots for saving the first 4 arguments which are passed in the registers `$a0-$a3`. Following them are all the remaining arguments. So, upon entry to your function, the 5th argument (the first one that is not passed via register) will be at address `16($sp)` with the 6th at `20($sp)` and the 7th at `24($sp)`. (This is assuming your arguments are 1 word each.) You subtract `36` from `$sp` to make space for your locals, thus after that all the offsets increase by that amount, i.e. 5th argument at `52($sp)` and so on. You can access them using these addresses.

You then set `$fp` to `$sp + 32`. I don't think calling convention mandates any particular value for `$fp`, so that should be fine. If you subsequently wish to access your arguments relative to `$fp`, you need to adjust the offsets again to compensate, this time by `-32`. Thus, 5th argument should be at `20($fp)`, followed by the rest.

Comment: `24($sp)` makes no sense, since that points into the area you have just allocated. Also note all conventions that I know place arguments consecutively in memory, so if you are sure the 5th is at `24($sp)` then the 6th must be at `28($sp)`. If it isn't, that means you are wrong about the 5th too.

Comment: I don't know what to say otherwise, but using the line I have now, 
lw $a3, 24($sp) returns triples for all cases
lw $t1, 28($sp) returns 0 when it should be returning home runs.
I have tested it.

I'll put the test/my output in the original problem since it doesn't format right here

Comment: @MichaelPetch did you notice the last sentence in my answer? :)

Comment: But then how is $a3 24($sp) working then? I'm not having any issues with the 5th argument.

Comment: Can be left-over memory garbage from previous instructions that happened to temporarily use that location for that argument.

Comment: So I decided to try something, and when I set $a3 to 28($sp), I got my home runs, and when I set it to 32($sp) I get my outs, so I've found the the 5th, 6th, and 7th arguments are in 24, 28, and 32, but what do I have to do to call those values to printStats to print them?

Comment: The Caller was setup by my prof as part of a test case. It can be trusted that everything else is setup properly, I just had to make the Callee return the 7 arguments (which I allocated space for $fp $ra, and 7 arguments) and call another method for printing

Comment: So soemthign that has me puzzled is that your `average` function seems to use an O32 calling convention where the first 4 parameters are passed in via registers `$a0` to `$a3` . However the call to `printStats` is using `$a0` to `$a3` for the parameters for walks, singles, doubles, triples but you use `$t1` and `$t2` for home runs and outs (instead of the stack). Did you professor give you a printStats routine and tell you it is special and that parameters are all passed in registers (`$a0`-`$a3` and `$t1` and `$t2`) .

Comment: Well I ran it in a debugger and my values are saving, but since they aren't calling in printStats maybe I'm not supposed to set them to the t registers? in printStats they're using 0($fp) for outs and -4($fp) for home runs, so I guess I'm not putting the values on the average callee stack onto the average caller stack for printStats?

Comment: Besides the comments above, you are correct - you aren't setting up the calling stack correctly. At a minimum you need to be pushing the parameters 5 and 6 on the stack, and you need to be allocating the space on the stack that is used as a scratch area for `$a0` to `$a3`. I am curious - is this [link](http://www.capp-sysware.com/misc/mipsbaseball.txt) pretty much your assignment? If so then you do need to use the stack correctly to pass those last 2 parameters. The link I have given is a copy of an assignment that looks similar to yours. I found it on the internet.

Comment: Yeah that's my program, except we only have to write the average function

Comment: So here's the thing:
I have 2 issues with this program right now.
The first is I'm not setting up the caller stack properly for printStats (the callee) to call and print the 6th and 7th arguments, but HOW do I do it? Like exactly what is the code I should write to put the values saved at $t1 and $t2 (they are saved, I checked the debugger) onto a stack for printStats?
The second problem I'm not returning my FP calculation to print properly. I set it to $f12 for printing, but the line mtc1 $v0, $f12 is changing $f12 from my calculation to 0, so I want to know HOW I get my value. Updating code

Comment: First off I have removed many of my comments. I realized after looking at the assignment code that Jester and I both guessed the same but wrong calling convention. We had no way to know. So all the calculations for the `$sp` and `$fp` don't apply. So pretty much you can ignore the stuff I had to say. @Jester alluded to in his first paragraph and the firsts entence of his second paragraph.

Comment: If I am seeing the assignment code correctly the function `average` has its 7th argument at `0($fp)` or `32($sp)`, the 6th argument at `-4($fp)` or `28($sp)` and the 5th argument at `-8($fp)` or `24($sp)`

Comment: You should be able to keep the two `lw` instruction (the ones that move data into `$t1` and `$t2` before you call printStats). Once they are moved into the temporary registers `$t1` and `$t2` you can move them onto the stack right after with instructions like `sw $t2, -4($sp)` and then a `sw $t1, -8($sp)` .

Comment: Oh alright, well at least we're on the same page now haha
Thanks for the help, but I figured that part out a short while ago, now I'm trying to solve the issue with $f12 not printing my calculation. Basically I have $f3 is a quotient of $f1 and $f2 and then I mov.s $f12, $f3, but when we jump back to main, the line mfc1 $v0, $f12 is changing my $f12 to 0.00000. Isn't $f12 the print register for single precision floating point registers?

Comment: @user3466773 I'd have to look it over tomorrow morning for any bug. But yes, when using `syscall` with `$v0` = 2 it will print the single precision float that is in register `$f12`

Comment: @user3466773 I may be wrong but in your average function aren't you suppose to be returning your floating point result in `$v0`? . Main should move `$v0` (returned from `average`) and move it into `$f12`. Then it will set `$v0` to 2 so that `syscall` will do the single precision print.

Comment: Yeah, it does. After (finally) passing a few cases, I ran into a bunch of other problems like preserving the $t, $f, $a, and $s registers properly so printStats can change them and it doesn't affect my output

Comment: @user3466773 It sounds like you are at least on your way to getting it all solved.

Comment: I've almost got it completely solved, I'm just failing one last recurring issue where some values are arbitrarily large. I'll update my code above.